# Control audio on remote computer using remote desktop (mstsc), and without console session

Tags: windows, audio, remote-desktop, console

I am using Windows 2003 server as a workstation computer.  Its soundcard is connected to my stereo speakers output.  Oftentimes, I want to play music on this computer through the speakers while my wife is using the computer and is logged into the console session.

How can I play control/play audio on this computer using remote desktop (mstsc), without logging in as console?

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way...

When you open up Remote Desktop, Expand options and then go to Local Resources.

You want to change the sound to "Leave at remote computer" on the old version.

[image]

On the new version, Click settings then select "Play on remote computer"

[image]